# Vim on Arch: /etc/vimrc can remap keys but not turn off syntax highlighting

Tags: linux, vim, arch-linux

Just freshly installed Arch, then installed vim. I added these two lines to my `/etc/vimrc`:

```
syntax off
inoremap jk <Esc>
```

I rebooted. The key remapping now works as expected but syntax highlighting is unaffected. I remember having this same problem on an old Ubuntu install. How can I turn off syntax highlighting by default?

<s>Update: Apparently, creating `~/.vimrc` and adding `syntax off` *can* turn syntax off by default for a *specific user*. But I still don't know how to set this as a *global* default.</s> I was mistaken, see my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

In `etc/vimrc` uncomment:

```
let skip_defaults vim=1
```

##### Story:

I tried adding `syntax off` to `~/.vimrc`, and that seemed to work. But then I was playing around and uncommented that line, and syntax was still off. It wasn't the *contents* of the file turning the syntax off, it was the *existence* of the file. Which reminded me of a comment in `/etc/vimrc`, so I went back and tried uncommenting the last line in

```
" do not load defaults if ~/.vimrc is missing
let skip_defaults vim=1
```

And that did it.

Comment: Do *your* customizing in `$HOME/.vimrc`.